# Getting duplicate page when activating my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-insert-post

I am creating a plugin in which I need to create a dynamic page and assign a template to it. I have created it using the code below:

```
function gallerypage() {    
    global $wpdb;
    $check_page = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'archive-gallery'" );

    if ( ! $check_page ) {
        $page_time = the_time( 'Y-m-d g:i:s' );
        $gallery_page = array(
            'post_title'    => 'Archive Gallery',
            'post_content'  => 'This page is dedicated to the archive gallery. and it is used to show all the gallerys',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'page',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_slug'     => 'archive-gallery',
            'post_date'     => $page_time
        );

        //$wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.'pn_options', array('option_value'=>$post_id), array('id'=>'10'));
        $p_ID = wp_insert_post( $gallery_page );
        update_post_meta( $p_ID, "_wp_page_template", "archivegallery.php" );
    }
} 
add_action( 'init', 'gallerypage' );
```

The problem is when I activate the plugin, the page is creating again and again, like stock market updates. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no result is found, `$wpdb->get_row` will return `NULL` not `false`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row

You are using `add_action('init', 'gallerypage');` so it runs on *every* load. You should be using  `register_activation_hook` so that it only runs when the plugin is activated. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Try using `get_page_by_path()` to check if the page already exists. Then you won't need to use the `$wpdb` global and custom sql. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path